# JQuery .show() not working for div inside an already referenced div

Tags: javascript, jquery

show() does not work

http://jsfiddle.net/Pppy6/5/

```
<div class="hello" id="hello">2<div class="ola" id="ola">showMe!</div></div>

.ola {
    display:none
}​

$('#hello').text(parseInt($('#hello').text()) + 1);
$('#ola').show();
```

Comment: *Right click -> Inspect Element ->* `<div class="hello" id="hello">3</div>` ... no `#ola` anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you call `.text()` to set the content, you obliterate the other element. The call to `.show()` doesn't work because the element is gone, in other words.

You could put the text inside a `<span>` element or something, and replace its text instead.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I was unaware of this. :)

Happy New Year, Pointy.

Answer (score 0):

what about this ?

```
<div class="hello" id="hello"><span>2</span><div class="ola" id="ola">showMe!</div></div>

.ola {
    display:none
}​

$('#hello').children('span').text(parseInt($('#hello').children('span').text()) + 1);
$('#ola').show();
```

this works if you are trying to `sum 1 to 2` in your `hello div`